# Transplanting Satsuma Tree and Need to Know the Root System

Tags: planting

I want to transplant a satsuma tree, and I need to know what the root system is on satsuma trees. I Have not tried any method, but I need to know how the roots run, and how far from tree to dig so as to not harm the roots.

Comment: How long has it been planted where it is? Can you add a photograph?